# Running Cypress with MSSQL- timing out

Tags: sql-server, timeout, cypress, cypress-task

I want to clean a database before running my test cases and I'm just having issues with it running. It just times out and I don't understand - hopefully you can help me :)

In the test case I have the following code block:

```
beforeEach(() => {
      cy.task("cleanUpDB", {
        sql:"UPDATE SQL GOES HERE"
      })
```

This then goes to my cypress.config file and the following is executed:

```
on("task", {
        cleanUpDB({ theQuery }) {
          return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
            try{
              await sql.connect(DBConfig)
            const result = await sql.query(theQuery);
            console.log(result)
            return resolve(result);
          }
          catch (err) {
              // ... error checks
             }
          }
          )
        }
      })
```

This is the error I get in the test runner:
[image]

Comment: what is the error you see on timeout?

Comment: @raju Added a pic of the error

Comment: which library are you using to connect with `mssql` ?

Comment: Yes, mssql :)

`"mssql": "^8.1.2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the same property name `sql` inside the task

```js
beforeEach(() => {
cy.task("cleanUpDB", {
  sql:"UPDATE SQL GOES HERE"
})
```

```js
on("task", {
  cleanUpDB({ sql }) {      // since you wrap the parameter
  ...                       // you must use the property name sql
```

or just pass in the query directly

```js
beforeEach(() => {
cy.task("cleanUpDB", "UPDATE SQL GOES HERE")
```

```js
on("task", {
  cleanUpDB(theQuery) {     // name can be anything
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I followed my original code and just made sure the property name was the same, it really was that simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation of the library, the below code should work.

```
const sqlQuery = 'UPDATE SQL GOES HERE';

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.task('cleanUpDB', {
    sqlQuery,
  });
});
```

// Config file

```
on('task', {
  cleanUpDB({ theQuery }) {
    sql.on('error', (err) => {
      // Error handling
    });
    sql
      .connect(DBConfig)
      .then((pool) => {
        return pool.request.query(theQuery);
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
});
```

Comment: this returned an error:

`The task 'cleanUpDB' returned undefined. You must return a value, null, or a promise that resolves to a value or null to indicate that the task was handled.`